# Find the limit of fraction involving logarithms

Tags: limits, logarithms, fractions

I am looking for a way to prove the following limit for integer $x$s:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{\log(x+2)-\log(x+1)}{\log(x+2)-\log(x)}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

I could find the result by using a computer program but I cannot formally establish the above equality.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities

Comment: I already did, but couldn't find anything useful

Comment: We can use L'Hospital's Rule once then a bit of algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may write, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{\log(x+2)-\log(x+1)}{\log(x+2)-\log(x)}=\frac{\log(1+\frac2x)-\log(1+\frac1x)}{\log(1+\frac2x)}=\frac{\frac1x+O(1/x^2)}{\frac2x+O(1/x^2)}=\frac12+O(1/x).
$$

Comment: Can you explain it a bit? I understand what you did with the denominator in the first equality but don't see the numerator. Also, can you explain how you switched from the second fraction to using big-O?

Comment: @gen Yes. I have used the Taylor series expansion applied to $ u \mapsto \log (1+u)$ which gives $\log (1+u)=u+O(u^2)$. Thanks.

Comment: The Taylor series expansion says, as $u \to a$, $f(u)=f(a)+\frac {f'(a)}{1!} (u-a)+O(u-a)^2$. Here $f(u)=\log(1+u)$, $f'(u)=\dfrac1{1+u}$, $a=0$.

Comment: can you explain what you did with the numerator?

Comment: @gen I've used $\log(x+2)-\log(x+1)=\log(x(1+2/x))-\log(x(1+1/x))=\log x +\log (1+2/x)-(\log x+\log (1+1/x))=\log(1+\frac2x)-\log(1+\frac1x).$

Comment: @gen You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) says,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\log(x+2)-\log(x+1)}{\log(x+2)-\log(x)}
&=\frac12\frac{\frac{\log(x+2)-\log(x+1)}{1}}{\frac{\log(x+2)-\log(x)}{2}}\\
&=\frac12\frac{\frac1{\xi_1}}{\frac1{\xi_0}}\\
&=\frac12\frac{\xi_0}{\xi_1}
\end{align}
$$
where $x+1\lt\xi_1\lt x+2$ and $x\lt\xi_0\lt x+2$. Therefore,
$$
\frac12\frac{x}{x+2}\le\frac{\log(x+2)-\log(x+1)}{\log(x+2)-\log(x)}\le\frac12\frac{x+2}{x+1}
$$
The [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), then says that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(x+2)-\log(x+1)}{\log(x+2)-\log(x)}=\frac12
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT : $\log(x+a)=\log(x)+\log(1+\frac{a}{x})$

Comment: can you explain how you intend to use this identity?

Comment: Just like Olivier Oloa did

Answer (score 0):

We will use the fundamental limit $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + x)}{x} = 1\tag{1}$$ We have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log(x + 2) - \log(x + 1)}{\log(x + 2) - \log x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{x + 2}{x + 1}\right)}{\log\left(\dfrac{x + 2}{x}\right)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\log\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{x + 1}\right)}{\log\left(1 + \dfrac{2}{x}\right)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\log\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{x + 1}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{x + 1}}\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x + 1}}{\dfrac{2}{x}}\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{2}{x}}{\log\left(1 + \dfrac{2}{x}\right)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + y)}{y}\cdot\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{x + 1}\cdot\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{z}{\log(1 + z)}\text{ (putting }y = 1/(x + 1), z = 2/x)\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\notag
\end{align}